# New emails are not shown in IMAP PHP

Tags: php, imap

```
$imap = imap_open("{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", "mail@mail.ru", "password");
while(true){
        $mails_id = imap_search($imap, 'NEW');
        foreach ($mails_id as $num) {
            // Letter header
            $header = imap_header($imap, $num);
            $body = imap_body($imap, $num);
            $fromAdress = mb_decode_mimeheader($header->fromaddress); //Отправитель
            $subject = mb_decode_mimeheader($header->subject); //Заголовок
            $body = strip_tags($body);
            echo $body . PHP_EOL;
        }
        sleep(2);
}
```

I run this code in the console (PHP CLI), send a message to the e-mail, but the script doesn't receive it. If I put ALL instead of the NEW flag, then when the script starts, it will parse all emails.

New messages are displayed only if I restart the thread. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: centos 7, php 7.3

Comment: It would be useful to send a NOOP command, which lets the server know that you’re ready for “new data”.  Checking every two seconds is also ridiculously frequent.

Comment: @Max What function should I use to send this command?

Comment: It appears the IMAP PHP version is “imap_ping()”